# Unity's PerResolveLifetimeManager for Repositories, Unit of Work and Entity Framework DBContext

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5, unity-container, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I want to inject repositories, services and UoW into app layer and inject a DBcontext into UoW and into Repositories.

DBContext must be the same context in UoW and every repositories in AppLayer, but must be disposed once the applayer is disposed and a new DBContext must be created in every AppLayer resolve.

Is it PerResolveLifetimeManager in the Unity's DBContext type mapping configuration suitable for this case?

Example:

```
//main
appLayer = resolve<IAppLayer>
appLayer.doSomeStuff()
appLayer.dispose()
// end main

//applayer class
public class AppLayer : IAppLayer{

  AppLayer(IRepository, IBusinesService, IUoW){...//init vbles} //ctor, dependencies injected by Unity

  public void doSomeStuff(){

    using(transactionScope){

      businessEntity = IRepository.findEntity()
      IBusinessService.modifyEntity(businessEntity) 
      IUoW.saveChanges() //works because IRepository is using the same DBContext to find the entity, so the entity is attached to the same DBContext.

    }//end using

  }//end doSomeStuff

}//end applayerclass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PerResolveLifetimeManager fits perfect for this scenario. I did a empirical test checking persistence cache and instances hash codes.

Comment: This answer makes me happy.